# How to iterate through parameters in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, iteration, parameter-passing

I have a model written as a for loop that incorporates a number of parameters that I specify:

```
## functions needed to run the model
learn <- function(prior, sensi, speci, e){
  out <- ifelse(e == 1, (sensi*prior) / ((sensi*prior) + (1-speci)*(1-prior)),
                ((1-sensi)*prior) / (((1-sensi)*prior) + (speci*(1-prior))))
  out
}

feed <- function(vec){
  prior <- 0.5
  for (i in vec){
    res <- learn(prior, sensi, speci, i)
    prior <- res
  }
  return(prior)
}

## specify parameters
iterations <- 100
N <- 10
BR <- 0.66
sensi <- 0.75
speci <- 0.45

## initialize results object
res <- NULL

## loop for number of iterations
for (j in 1:iterations){
  
  X <- as.numeric(rbinom(1, 1, BR))
  
  if (X == 1){ # if X is 1...
    agents <- c(1:N) 
    evidence <- vector("list", length(agents)) 
    for (i in agents) {
      n <- sample(10, 1, replace = TRUE) 
      evidence[[i]] <- rbinom(n, 1, sensi) 
    }
  } else { # if X is 0... 
    agents <- c(1:N)
    evidence <- vector("list", length(agents)) 
    for (i in agents) {
      n <- sample(10, 1, replace = TRUE) 
      evidence[[i]] <- rbinom(n, 1, sensi) 
      evidence[[i]] <- ifelse(evidence[[i]]==1, 0, 1) # flip evidence 
    }
  }
  
  # feed vectors of evidence through learn function
  t0 <- sapply(evidence, feed)
  
  # save dataframe 
  df <- data.frame("i" = j, 
                   "ID" = c(1:N), 
                   "E" = t0, 
                   "X" = X,
                   "N" = N, 
                   "BR" = BR,
                   "sensi" = sensi,
                   "speci" = speci)

  res <- rbind(res, df)
  
}
```

This works fine for a single parameterisation, but I now want to automate the process of specifying different parameter values and re-running the model. So instead of defining each parameter as a single value, I define them as a vector of values and store all the possible parameterisations in a dataframe (`paramspace`) with each row holding the values for a single parameterisation that I want to run:

```
## set up for multiple parameterizations 
iterations <- 100
N_vec <- c(10, 50)
BR_vec <- c(0.25, 0.50, 0.75) 
sensi_vec <- c(0.45, 0.75)
speci_vec <- c(0.45, 0.75)

paramspace <- expand.grid(iterations = iterations, N = N_vec, BR = BR_vec, sensi = sensi_vec, speci = speci_vec)

> paramspace
   iterations  N   BR sensi speci
1         100 10 0.25  0.45  0.45
2         100 50 0.25  0.45  0.45
3         100 10 0.50  0.45  0.45
4         100 50 0.50  0.45  0.45
5         100 10 0.75  0.45  0.45
6         100 50 0.75  0.45  0.45
7         100 10 0.25  0.75  0.45
8         100 50 0.25  0.75  0.45
9         100 10 0.50  0.75  0.45
10        100 50 0.50  0.75  0.45
11        100 10 0.75  0.75  0.45
12        100 50 0.75  0.75  0.45
13        100 10 0.25  0.45  0.75
14        100 50 0.25  0.45  0.75
15        100 10 0.50  0.45  0.75
16        100 50 0.50  0.45  0.75
17        100 10 0.75  0.45  0.75
18        100 50 0.75  0.45  0.75
19        100 10 0.25  0.75  0.75
20        100 50 0.25  0.75  0.75
21        100 10 0.50  0.75  0.75
22        100 50 0.50  0.75  0.75
23        100 10 0.75  0.75  0.75
24        100 50 0.75  0.75  0.75
```

*How can I pass each row of parameter values to my model and automatically run through all the parameterisations stated in `paramspace`?*

Comment: You could turn your code into a function, then use `apply(paramspace,1, my_function)` to pass `paramspace` into your function row-by-row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the `foreach` package, that used with an appropriate backend offers parallelization capabilities, in case your task becomes more intensive. Here a simple example to understand how it works.

```
foreach(a=1:3, b=4:6) %do% (a + b)
```

Then I tried to embed your code into `foreach`

```
require(foreach)

## functions needed to run the model
learn <- function(prior, sensi, speci, e){
  out <- ifelse(e == 1, (sensi*prior) / ((sensi*prior) + (1-speci)*(1-prior)),
                ((1-sensi)*prior) / (((1-sensi)*prior) + (speci*(1-prior))))
  out
}

feed <- function(vec){
  prior <- 0.5
  for (i in vec){
    res <- learn(prior, sensi, speci, i)
    prior <- res
  }
  return(prior)
}


## set up for multiple parameterizations 
iterations <- 100
N_vec <- c(10, 50)
BR_vec <- c(0.25, 0.50, 0.75) 
sensi_vec <- c(0.45, 0.75)
speci_vec <- c(0.45, 0.75)

paramspace <- expand.grid(iterations = iterations, N = N_vec, BR = BR_vec, sensi = sensi_vec, speci = speci_vec)

res <- foreach(iterations = paramspace$iterations, 
               N = paramspace$N, 
               BR = paramspace$BR, 
               sensi = paramspace$sensi, 
               speci = paramspace$speci) %do% {
                 
                 ## initialize results object
                 res <- NULL
                 
                 ## loop for number of iterations
                 for (j in 1:iterations){
                   
                   X <- as.numeric(rbinom(1, 1, BR))
                   
                   if (X == 1){ # if X is 1...
                     agents <- c(1:N) 
                     evidence <- vector("list", length(agents)) 
                     for (i in agents) {
                       n <- sample(10, 1, replace = TRUE) 
                       evidence[[i]] <- rbinom(n, 1, sensi) 
                     }
                   } else { # if X is 0... 
                     agents <- c(1:N)
                     evidence <- vector("list", length(agents)) 
                     for (i in agents) {
                       n <- sample(10, 1, replace = TRUE) 
                       evidence[[i]] <- rbinom(n, 1, sensi) 
                       evidence[[i]] <- ifelse(evidence[[i]]==1, 0, 1) # flip evidence 
                     }
                   }
                   
                   # feed vectors of evidence through learn function
                   t0 <- sapply(evidence, feed)
                   
                   # save dataframe 
                   df <- data.frame("i" = j, 
                                    "ID" = c(1:N), 
                                    "E" = t0, 
                                    "X" = X,
                                    "N" = N, 
                                    "BR" = BR,
                                    "sensi" = sensi,
                                    "speci" = speci)
                   
                   res <- rbind(res, df)
                   
                 }
                 
                 res
                 
               }
```

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in comments, you can create a function and then use `apply` to loop over the parameters combinations :

```
## functions needed to run the model
learn <- function(prior, sensi, speci, e){
  out <- ifelse(e == 1, (sensi*prior) / ((sensi*prior) + (1-speci)*(1-prior)),
                ((1-sensi)*prior) / (((1-sensi)*prior) + (speci*(1-prior))))
  out
}

feed <- function(vec,sensi,speci){
  prior <- 0.5
  for (i in vec){
    res <- learn(prior, sensi, speci, i)
    prior <- res
  }
  return(prior)
}

runModel <- function(iterations = 100,
                     N = 10,
                     BR = 0.66,
                     sensi = 0.75,
                     speci = 0.45 ) {
  ## initialize results object
  res <- NULL
  
  ## loop for number of iterations
  for (j in 1:iterations){
    
    X <- as.numeric(rbinom(1, 1, BR))
    
    if (X == 1){ # if X is 1...
      agents <- c(1:N) 
      evidence <- vector("list", length(agents)) 
      for (i in agents) {
        n <- sample(10, 1, replace = TRUE) 
        evidence[[i]] <- rbinom(n, 1, sensi) 
      }
    } else { # if X is 0... 
      agents <- c(1:N)
      evidence <- vector("list", length(agents)) 
      for (i in agents) {
        n <- sample(10, 1, replace = TRUE) 
        evidence[[i]] <- rbinom(n, 1, sensi) 
        evidence[[i]] <- ifelse(evidence[[i]]==1, 0, 1) # flip evidence 
      }
    }
    
    # feed vectors of evidence through learn function
    #t0 <- sapply(evidence, feed)
    t0 <- sapply(evidence,function(e){feed(e,sensi,speci)})
    
    # save dataframe 
    df <- list("i" = iterations, 
               "ID" = c(1:N), 
               "E" = t0, 
               "X" = X,
               "N" = N, 
               "BR" = BR,
               "sensi" = sensi,
               "speci" = speci)
    
    res <- rbind(res, df)
    
  }
  res
}

# Define parameter space
iterations <- 100
N_vec <- c(10, 50)
BR_vec <- c(0.25, 0.50, 0.75) 
sensi_vec <- c(0.45, 0.75)
speci_vec <- c(0.45, 0.75)

paramspace <- expand.grid(iterations = iterations, N = N_vec, BR = BR_vec, sensi = sensi_vec, speci = speci_vec)

# Loop over parameter space :
res <- apply(paramspace,1,function(paramset) {
  iterations = paramset[1]
  N = paramset[2]
  BR = paramset[3]
  sensi = paramset[4]
  speci = paramset[5]
  runModel(iterations = iterations, N = N, BR = BR , sensi = sensi, speci = speci )
})
```

Comment: I encountered some problems with the code you provided. Please see my response added in the original post.

Comment: I guess this is due to `t0 <- sapply(evidence, feed)` which doesn't get the updated parameters. Correction in a few minutes.

Comment: this was it : I updated feed function to pass to it speci / sensi parameters. Still some warnings, but not when you run `RunModel()` alone, ie with initial parameter set. I guess that some parameters combinations produce these warnings.

Comment: loop over model runs properly, warning comes from the dataframe call to save results : df <- data.frame("i" = j,...). What is your intention when writing "i"=j? I don't see j explicitly defined in the code. This results in j being equal to 1 in all results.

Comment: My intention was to label the iteration in the results. Maybe my variables got mixed up somewhere along the way. I can look into this.

Comment: the warnings come from the fact that you try to save in a dataframe vectors of different lengths : 100 iterations, 10 IDs, 1 X,... . R accepts this because it recycles the shortest vectors, but it gives a warning because this is perhaps not what you intend to do...

Comment: Did you consider using a list of lists instead of a dataframe to store the results?

Comment: I wouldn't mind storing the results as a list of lists and converting it to a dataframe separately (outside of the loop/function). But I still haven't been able to resolve the warnings, and when trying to scale up this solution with other code I'm working with, the warnings appear and the results do not save. So resolving the warnings seems important.

Comment: see edit : results saved as list - no warnings anymore

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to make a function and to use `Map(...)`. The advantage of `Map` is that your `paramspace` will not be coerced into a matrix which will make everything the same type (i.e., numeric, character, etc.).

There were also some other changes I made in order to allow R to do the acccounting for us. Primarily:

1. `X` is now a logical so we can simplify our `if` statements. Additionally, the allocation is made all at once instead of looping.
2. We change the `feed()` function to also generate the `evidence`. This allows us to...
3. Use `replicate` to repeat the loops.

```r
learn2 <- function(prior, sensi, speci, e){
    out <- ifelse(e, (sensi*prior) / ((sensi*prior) + (1-speci)*(1-prior)),
                  ((1-sensi)*prior) / (((1-sensi)*prior) + (speci*(1-prior))))
    out
}


feed2  = function(x, N, samp_n = 10L, sensi, speci) {
    evidence = rbinom(sample(samp_n, 1L, replace = TRUE), 
                      1,
                      if (x) sensi else 1 - sensi)
    
    prior = 0.5
    for (i in evidence) {
        res = learn2(prior, sensi, speci, i)
        prior = res
    }
    return(prior)
}

runModel2 <- function(iterations = 2,
                     N = 10,
                     BR = 0.66,
                     sensi = 0.75,
                     speci = 0.45 ) {
    
    X = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), N, BR)
    
    ## this is done now so that the columns will be ordered nicer
    ans = list(ID = 1:N,
                N = N,
               BR = BR,
               sensi = sensi,
               speci = speci,
               X = X)
    
    t0s = replicate(iterations,
                    vapply(X, feed2, FUN.VALUE = 0, N, 10L, sensi, speci, USE.NAMES = FALSE), 
                    simplify = FALSE)
    
    names(t0s) = paste0("E_", 1:iterations)
    
    return(as.data.frame(c(ans, t0s)))
}

runModel2()
#>    ID  N   BR sensi speci     X        E_1         E_2
#> 1   1 10 0.66  0.75  0.45  TRUE 0.82967106 0.657648599
#> 2   2 10 0.66  0.75  0.45 FALSE 0.43103448 0.006827641
#> 3   3 10 0.66  0.75  0.45  TRUE 0.43103448 0.775671866
#> 4   4 10 0.66  0.75  0.45  TRUE 0.71716957 0.431034483
#> 5   5 10 0.66  0.75  0.45 FALSE 0.24176079 0.016593958
#> 6   6 10 0.66  0.75  0.45 FALSE 0.30303324 0.008992838
#> 7   7 10 0.66  0.75  0.45  TRUE 0.82967106 0.865405260
#> 8   8 10 0.66  0.75  0.45 FALSE 0.43103448 0.439027817
#> 9   9 10 0.66  0.75  0.45 FALSE 0.57692308 0.050262167
#> 10 10 10 0.66  0.75  0.45 FALSE 0.02178833 0.296208531
```

This output is a little wider than your original approach. We can always reshape the `E_#` columns but this may end up being better for your actual use case.

Finally, here is `Map()` in action:

```r
iterations <- 100
N_vec <- c(10, 50)
BR_vec <- c(0.25, 0.50, 0.75) 
sensi_vec <- c(0.45, 0.75)
speci_vec <- c(0.45, 0.75)

paramspace <- expand.grid(iterations = iterations, N = N_vec, BR = BR_vec, sensi = sensi_vec, speci = speci_vec)

res = Map(runModel2, paramspace$iterations, paramspace$N, paramspace$BR, paramspace$sensi, paramspace$speci)

res[[24L]][1:10, 1:8] ## only first 10 rows for demonstration
##   ID  N   BR sensi speci     X         E_1         E_2
##1   1 50 0.75  0.75  0.75  TRUE 0.500000000 0.500000000
##2   2 50 0.75  0.75  0.75 FALSE 0.001369863 0.035714286
##3   3 50 0.75  0.75  0.75 FALSE 0.250000000 0.900000000
##4   4 50 0.75  0.75  0.75  TRUE 0.750000000 0.250000000
##5   5 50 0.75  0.75  0.75  TRUE 0.987804878 0.500000000
##6   6 50 0.75  0.75  0.75  TRUE 0.964285714 0.250000000
##7   7 50 0.75  0.75  0.75  TRUE 0.750000000 0.750000000
##8   8 50 0.75  0.75  0.75 FALSE 0.012195122 0.035714286
##9   9 50 0.75  0.75  0.75  TRUE 0.750000000 0.500000000
##10 10 50 0.75  0.75  0.75 FALSE 0.250000000 0.001369863
```